# Convert Sequencer and MIDI code to Java 8 lambda and stream

Tags: java-8, stream, midi, javax.sound.midi

I am converting a code written in java 6 into java 8. 
The code acts as an event notifier in my game where a sound is played on every event. My code is as follows:

```
public void play() {
    try {
        Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        player.open();
        Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
        Track tr = seq.createTrack();

        ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
        a.setMessage(144, 1, 50, 100);
        MidiEvent on = new MidiEvent(a, 1);
        tr.add(on);
        ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
        b.setMessage(128, 1, 50, 100);
        MidiEvent off = new MidiEvent(b, 10);
        tr.add(off);
        player.setSequence(seq);
        player.setTempoInBPM(220);
        player.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am not getting a way of how to convert it into Java 8. Can anybody help out?

Comment: What's the point of the upgrading it to 8?

Comment: To improve other processing used elsewhere in game, and in different logics written.

Comment: Well,these lines look fine with java 8,there's no place for those lambdas or sth else